# fluid image width, matching height

Tags: css

I am trying (if it is at all possible) to use css to make an image 100% the width of a fluid div, but as the images are square (and will be distorted if not square) I want to be able to match the height to the width... for fluid width I am using:

```
.img{
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
}
```

which works fine for setting the width on all major browsers, but I just cant figure out how to match the height to the width :/

Comment: provided you don't have the height set for it somewhere else, it should automatically adjust itself and stay in proportion

Comment: Is there browsers you're having trouble with specifically. I thought most should scale them fine, but maybe I haven't had enough coffee. Have you tried throwing a height: auto; on there?

Comment: ill try the auto real quick and let you know thanks :)

Comment: As SmokeyPHP said though, it really should be adjusting itself, unless something odd is going on with the max- min-.

Comment: idk what was going on but height: auto; worked fine, throw that up as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks!

Comment: the browser that was giving me trouble was firefox, all the images look crap on there even when they are in proportion though, all pixelated -.- but thats a whole different battle :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try throwing in `height:auto` into your class.

```
.img{
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: auto; // <-- add me
}
```

As mentioned in the comments though, most browsers should be adjusting and scaling the images correctly. But glad this could help.

Answer (score 1):

Now, with CSS3 there is new units that are measured relative to the viewport, (browser window), if you want a fluid image with respect to the window this it works better in most use cases than "%". These are vh and vw, which measure viewport height and width, respectively.

```
.img{
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 100vw;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```